# How to use Google Script Send email with group account

Tags: javascript, email, gmail, logic

I want to send an email with Google Script, but I need to use the public (group) mailbox,

I didn't find an example of sending email from the group account on the Google API, and I couldn't find the answer on the stack overflow. Could you please tell me if there is a method that use google script send email with group account?

Answer (score 5):

I have solved the problem.
from "Account and import" add your group account then You can reference below code to test whether you can send an email in group account.

```
  var alias = GmailApp.getAliases();
  var num = alias.length-1;
  var myMail = getMyMail();

  if (num<0){
    return false
  }else{
    for (var i = 0;i <= num;i++){
      if (alias[i] == "yourGroup@Domain.com"){
        var myGroupMail=alias[i];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (myGroupMail != "yourGroup@Domain.com"){return false}
  GmailApp.sendEmail(toEmail,strSubject,strContent,{from : myGroupMail});
```

Comment: couldn't thank you enough, i was trying to use var alias = GmailApp.getAliases(); and {from : alias["yourGroup@Domain.com"]} but i couldn't understand why it can't work (kept sending from my main individual account. but your solution is perfect! thanks!