# Sending emails via google apps script from a different email?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I volunteer with an animal rescue and we hired a freelancer to make a sheet that grabs form data for a new volunteer to create a gsuite email, and we can select which groups to invite them to, invite to shared drive and also to some reoccurring meeting events, finally send a welcome email

It works fine, the only issue is we have to use the vol@ account to process the script as the freelancer said if we use another account the emails will be sent from that account, typically we give our volunteer coordinator delegated access to the vol@ so they wouldnt have access to that accounts GAS/ sheet

Is this just a limitation of how GAS works or is there a workaround to access the sheet from another account and process it but have the emails come from vol@?

Comment: I don't understand your explanation but in answer to your question you may use aliases that you have already created with Gmail

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Google Apps Script is the "problem" here...

[Class GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) and [Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail) are the Google Apps Script services that might send emails. They send the emails from the effective user mailbox.

Class GmailApp could be set to send emails using an alias set on effective user mailbox. See [sendEmail(recipient,subject,body,options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

It's possible to use the Gmail API and Google Workspace domain-wide delegation of authority to send emails from any user of the organization.

Related

- [Is there any workaround to specify sender's email address for automatic email sending upon form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65212715/1595451)